# Android: Null Pointer Exception setContentView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

What I is wrong?
If I click on the Registrieren Button, the app will be stopped.
Project files:
https://github.com/JonasFranzDEV/LaMamma

Comment: check id of your button, and post your code here

Comment: post log cat and code

Comment: Instead of github link for all project try posting code which can cause Issue , for instance Registrieren Button's onClickListener's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have View Hierarchy loaded at the time calling `findViewById()` to actually get view's instance else It will be null.

In your following code views are from two different layouts and only views from current layout will be initialised and others will be null causing `NullPointerException`:

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
r_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
r_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
r_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
registerForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```

Also in your following code you have set click listener for registerForm Button by typecasting Button into OnClickListener which can cause `ClassCastException`:

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        registerForm.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) register);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check and confirm whether the fields are exists in the activity_main.xml
.

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
r_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
r_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
r_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
registerForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `activity_main` layout doesn't have a view with id `register` and your `registerform` remains `null`.

Obtain the reference to the `register` view with `findViewById()` when your view hierarchy actually has that view, i.e. after the second `setContentView()` (having another `setContentView()` isn't such a good idea by the way).

Also, you should include the relevant code and exception stacktrace in the question and not just link to a github project.

Answer (score 0):

Intiallize your Buttons, EditTexts in your Activity..

In this manner:-

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
r_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
r_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
r_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
registerForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```